# What is the best way in Category Theory to define all subcategories of a category, but with a specific structure?

Tags: category-theory

For example consider a category $A$ which is defined only by the following arrows
$a\to b$, $a\to c$, $c\to d$, $c\to e$, and with no composition rules.

How would we define a category of subcategories of $A$, that contain arrows $a\to b$, $a\to c$.

E.g. For $A$ this category would include the following categories:

- $a\to b$, $a\to c$
- $a\to b$, $a\to c$, $c\to d$
- $a\to b$, $a\to c$, $c\to e$
- $a\to b$, $a\to c$, $c\to d$, $c\to e$

This is a simple example but there could be more complex arrow structures and so the method would need to be expressive enough to do this for arbitrary categories.

Comment: When you say "maintain". I think you mean "contain", in which case you have given a definition of the objects of your category and you just have to decide what the arrows are (inclusion is the obvious choice). In your example, you have missed the cases where one or both of the objects $d$ and $e$ are included but with no arrow from $c$ to them.

Comment: @RobArthan Ah I don't want to allow objects such as those in the category. So I guess I need to add an extra constraint for this like, all objects of the subcategories must have greater than 1 arrow?

Comment: Sure: you could say that every object must the domain or codomain of at least two arrows.

Comment: @RobArthan Thankyou. When defining the structure of A would it be possible to group a->b, a->c in a single category (X) and then say A contains an object which is the category X, and this object has an arrow to d and e, and all this will give the same structure as the original A definition.

Comment: You could start by introducing the category of all subcategories of $A$ and then say that you want the ones that contain $X$ (and meet whatever other restrictions you want to impose). By the way, it is usual to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical formulas on this site.

Comment: @RobArthan ok thanks and will do.

Comment: What you define cannot be a category. A category requires that if you have an arrow $a\to c$ and an arrow $c\to d$, then you can compose them to get an arrow $a\to d$. You can't just say "no composition rules".

Comment: (Also, categories require identity arrows; are you including them sub silentio, or trying to exclude them? Do you actually want categories, or do you want directed graphs?)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin When I say no composition rules, I mean no additional rules to the standard ones which I guess are implicit to all categories, like the transitive composition you mention here. Does this make sense or am I missing something?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes i'm including them implicitly.

Comment: Then it makes no sense to say "no composition rules". What "additional rule" do you believe there may be in a category? Simply, the definition is that if you have two arrows, and the target of one equals the source of the other, then you can compose them and get a unique arrow from the source of the first to the target of the second, and composition is associative. I can't think of any "additional rule" in any category...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I believe transitive composition is default, hence there is no need to explicitly define rules to transitively compose arrows, but what if we take your example $a \to b$ and $b \to c$, and we wanted to prevent the transitive composition, we would have to add an explicit composition rule right?

Comment: My point is that when you say "no composition rules", you seem to be trying to **exclude** the usual composition. You said you included that statement because you were trying to prevent some "additional rules", and I am asking what kind of additional rules have you ever seen that you believe need to be excluded explicitly: I don't know of any "additional rules" in any category I am familiar with, and I am wondering if you know of any. If you don't, then you should just not say anything and say something like "plus identities and obvious compositions" and leave it at that.

Comment: And if you wanted to prevent the compostion of an arrow $a\to b$ with an arrow $b\to c$, then you would need to **not** do Category Theory. Category Theory doesn't let you do that kind of exclusion.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ok so what are composition definitions for in that case? I have seen examples of explicit composition definitions. Why not just have arrows? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806382/what-is-a-composition-in-category-theory shows explicit composition defined.

Comment: what are you refering to with "that case"? **Which** case? As to the link, that doesn't give any "extra rules" for composition. It says you need to be able to compose functions when target matches source. I don't understand the question of "why not just have arrows". It seems nonsensical to me.

Comment: "Ok so what are composition definitions for in that case", the example you provided, $a \to b$, $b \to c$, you can't add anything more here

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm just starting to learn category theory, I believe a category is defined as a set of objects, with morphisms and composition, where I believe default composition is transitive where if we have $a \to b$, $b \to c$, there must be $a \to c$. I figure defining composition rules means we either override this default behaviour, or we add to it which either adds more morphisms compared to the defined ones, or removes them?

Comment: A category is a collection of objects, a collection of arrows, and a "composition" relation/partial operation that is associative, and which given an arrow $f\colon a\to b$ and an arrow $g\colon b\to c$, yields and arrow $g\circ f\colon a\to c$; and identity arrows for each object that act like neutral elements for composition. You cannot "override default behavior", because this is a **requirement** for you to have a category. If you change these rules, then *you aren't doing category theory*, you are doing something else.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so what does it mean to define composition for a category, surely its more than just adding arrows? In the first answer to this question they define two different composition operators, why do this if composition already given by the arrows? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806382/what-is-a-composition-in-category-theory

Comment: You can specify which arrow you mean when you write $g\circ f$ if it already has a name; but you aren't "overriding default behavior", you are giving a special name to $g\circ f$. It's alike addition: you don't "override default behavior" of addition when you say that $1+2=3$. You are just giving a name to "$1+2$". And I *already* saw that link, you don't need to shove it in my direction yet again just to have me say, yet again, "they are not doing what you think they are doing".

Comment: Look, when you said "no composition rules", what you projected was not what you thought you were projecting. Instead, you said something which can easily be misunderstood as you saying that you **not** allowing composition, even though to be a category you must allow it. Your choice of words was extremely poor, and your further attempts at justifying that choice of words doesn't help that poor choice, it just suggests you aren't terribly clear on what "composition" means in this context.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sorry i'm not trying to throw anything in your face, I'm just trying to learn, thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Given any category $\mathbf{C}$, with objects $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathbf{C})$ and for each ordered pair of objects $(X,Y)$ a collection of arrows $\mathbf{C}(X,Y)$, with compositions when defined and identity functions, you define a subcategory $\mathbf{D}$ as a category with $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathbf{D})\subseteq \mathrm{Ob}(\mathbf{C})$, and for each $X,Y\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathbf{D})$, $\mathbf{D}(X,Y)\subseteq \mathbf{C}(X,Y)$, with the proviso that the identity functions must be included in $\mathbf{D}(X,X)$ for each $X\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathbf{D})$, and the compositions (when defined) of arrows in $\mathbf{D}$ must lie in $\mathbf{D}$.

If $\mathbf{D}$ is a subcategory of $\mathbf{C}$, then there is a natural "inclusion functor $\mathbf{I}\colon\mathbf{D}\hookrightarrow\mathbf{C}$, given by mapping each $X\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathbf{D})$ to itself in $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathbf{C})$, and likewise mapping $\mathbf{D}(X,Y)$ to $\mathbf{C}(X,Y)$ via the inclusion map of sets/classes.

Given any collection of categories $\{\mathbf{C}_i\}$, you can construct a category $\mathbf{D}$ whose objects are precisely the categories $\mathbf{C}_i$, and where $\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{C}_i,\mathbf{C}_j)$ consists precisely of the functors $C_i\to C_j$. This is a full subcategory of $\mathbf{Cat}$, the category of categories. But you can define a non-full subcategory by restricting the functors you allow to any specific subcollection of functors that you will "allow".

So you can simply start with your category $\mathbf{C}$; then specify the subcategory of $\mathbf{Cat}$ whose objects are the subcategories of $\mathbf{C}$ (categories that have an "inclusion functor" to $\mathbf{C}$ as defined above), and that include certain morphisms (and you may also specify that they should exclude "isolated objects", or exclude certain morphisms/objects, if you want); and whose arrows (for these family of categories viewed as a subcategory of $\mathbf{Cat}$)  are the inclusion functors (or any particular family of functors that you wish to allow).